# Download Highcharts Generated Table into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, highcharts

I'm trying to download a csv file of data corresponding to the chart on the below website:

http://vixcentral.com/

If I click on the menu button on the top right of the chart there's an option to download the chart data into a csv.

The issue is that that button seems to generate a download link that only works temporarily, so I'm unable to use a regular downloader such as read_csv or rio::import to pull the file into R.

It seems both the chart and the download link are generated by the Highcharts javascript.

Is there any straightforward way to download this data into R by figuring out the link?

Or does it have to be a scraping excercise?

Comment: Which of the charts do you want the data for? If you right-click on the screen and press 'Inspect Element', then go to the 'Network' tab, you can see xhr requests being done to obtain data (for example while clicking around the different charts). If you find which of the request's data you want, you can create a request with the appropriate headers to obtain your data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm interested in the chart on the first tab called VIX Term Months. This request seems to have the data I want in response when I inspect (http://vixcentral.com/ajax_update/?_=1590762673737) but trying to import it with rjson doesn't seem to work. The URL also seems to change not sure if that's a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click on the screen and press 'Inspect Element', then go to the 'Network' tab, you can see xhr requests being done to obtain data (for example while clicking around the different charts).

You noted that you're interested in the result of http://vixcentral.com/ajax_update/?_=1590762673737.
The number in the end of this URL is the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of the current time. That's why it changes.

There is a little bit of security from scraping in the sense that they try to block requests that do not come from their own site. By setting the header `X-Requested-With` to `"XMLHttpRequest"`, it works. You can view the headers used for this request by clicking on it in the 'inspect element' screen of your browser. There are a bunch of headers being set, and by removing each one and testing, I found out that this is the only one that's needed for your purpose.

Below reads the data and parses it into an R object using `jsonlite`.

```
res <- httr::GET("http://vixcentral.com/ajax_update/?_=1590762673737",
                 add_headers("X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"))

res_text <- content(res, "text")

jsonlite::fromJSON(res_text)
```